# problema al ejecutar vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Soy totalmente novato en este lenguaje, he intentado hacer esto, per a mi no me funciona.
Podeis orientarme un poco. Muchas gracias

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Escript de ejecución directa</title>
</head>
<body>
    Según se carga la página vamos a ver
    la versión del navegado en una caja de diálogo.
    <script language=vbscript>
        msgbox(navigator.appVersion)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! vbscript sigue existiendo?

Comment: Hasta donde se Google Chrome no brinda soporte a dicho lenguaje de scripting, ¿en cuál lo estás tratando de usar?

Comment: Tomado de [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript): *VBScript sólo está disponible para el navegador de Microsoft Internet Explorer y no en otros como Firefox, Google Chrome u Opera (en sus diferentes versiones)*. Si estás empezando en programación, mi sugerencia es que acudas a otro lenguaje. Saludos

Comment: Lo intento con IE  pero nada

Answer (score 0):

VBScript ya no es soportado en IE11. Debes transformar tu página a ASP donde aún puedes usar VBScript. Sería algo así:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Escript de ejecución directa</title>
</head>
<body>
    Según se carga la página vamos a ver
    la versión del navegado en una caja de diálogo.
    <%=msgbox(navigator.appVersion)%>
</body>
</html>
```

...luego esa página debe llamarse mipagina.asp

Comment: Hola! Esto no está considerado una buena respuesta por la comunidad, debería ser un comentario. Las respuestas tienen que ser claras y concisas, abordando y explicando el problema. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) así ayudarás mejor a los demás y ganarás más resputación!

Comment: No veo la diferencia con el código original. Me parece que sólo reubicastes la declaración del script.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript es un lenguaje obsoleto y no debería usarse. En el pasado, sólo Internet Explorer daba soporte a ese lenguaje (que ya en sí sería un buen motivo para no recomendar su uso), pero desde 2016 ya ni eso: [a partir de Internet Explorer 11, VBScript no tiene soporte tampoco en ese navegador](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/dn384057(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN): (traducción propia)

> Desde Internet Explorer 11, VBScript se considera obsoleto y no debería usarse como lenguaje de scripting en IE11. Las páginas web mostradas en modo IE11 no ejecutarán el código VBScript.
>
> Como VBScript ya no tiene soporte en modo IE11, las siguientes características de la API no estarán disponibles en las páginas web:
>
> - La función execScript.
> - El objecto VBArray.
> - Los tipos MIME "text/vbs" y "text/vbscript" (como valores soportados en elementos script).
>
> Actualize todas las páginas que usen VBScript para que usen JavaScript. Si no es posible, intenta remplazar la página web por una app desarrollada con Visual Basic.
>
> Por motivos de compatibilidad, VBScript se seguirá ejecutando en modos de documento anticuados (el modo de estándar IE10 y anteriores), de todos modos, esto debería considerarse una solución temporal.

Ese es el motivo por el que no se ejecuta tu código ni siquiera en Internet Explorer: el navegador ya no da soporte a ese lenguaje.